# How can I do bind any ip to socks5 server in C#?

Tags: ip, bind, socks, any

i have a problem for ip bind to Socks5.
i've several ip addresses.

all of the incoming connections was bind to default ip.
how can do bind any ip without default ip?

any body help me?
thanks

here is part of my code.

```
        Console.WriteLine("new client connected: " + socksClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        NetworkStream socksClientStream = socksClient.GetStream();
        /* *****************************************************
         * supported methods part
         * ***************************************************** */
        byte[] authFields = new byte[2];
        socksClientStream.Read(authFields, 0, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("authFields: version {0} methods {1}", authFields[0], authFields[1]));
        // read n supported methods 
        byte[] methods = new byte[authFields[1]];
        socksClientStream.Read(methods, 0, methods.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("socks client supports " + methods.Length.ToString() + " methods");
        /* *****************************************************
         * method selection part
         * ***************************************************** */
        byte[] selectedAuthMethod = { SOCKS_VERSION, SOCKS_NOAUTH };
        socksClientStream.Write(selectedAuthMethod, 0, 2);

        // return version and auth method "no auth"

        byte[] requestFields = new byte[4];
        socksClientStream.Read(requestFields, 0, 4);
        Console.WriteLine("socksclient requests address type " + requestFields[3].ToString());

        // adresstypes ipv4 and hostname are supported
        string connection_target = "";
        int target_port;
        if (requestFields[3] == SOCKS_IPV4ADDR )
        {
            //ip4v adress is requested
            byte[] target_data = new byte[4];
            socksClientStream.Read(target_data, 0, 4);
            IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(target_data);
            connection_target = ip.ToString();
        }
        else if (requestFields[3] == SOCKS_DNSNAME )
        {
            //domainname requested
            //doc: byteorder
            byte[] domainname_length = new byte[1];
            // read the following domain name length
            socksClientStream.Read(domainname_length, 0, 1);
            byte[] target_data = new byte[domainname_length[0]];
            // read a domain name of requseted length
            socksClientStream.Read(target_data, 0, domainname_length[0]);
            //interpret the domainname in default encoding
            connection_target = Encoding.Default.GetString(target_data);
        }
        else
        {
            //unsupported addresstype
            Console.WriteLine("unsupported addresstype " + requestFields[3].ToString());

        }

        //if requested address is supported
        if (connection_target != "")
        {

           /* *****************************************************
           * server client connection part
           * ***************************************************** */


            //doc: byteorder
            byte[] bintargetport = new byte[2];
            socksClientStream.Read(bintargetport, 0, 2);
            byte[] tmp_byteorder = new byte[2];
            tmp_byteorder[0] = bintargetport[1];
            tmp_byteorder[1] = bintargetport[0];
            target_port = (int)BitConverter.ToUInt16(tmp_byteorder, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("requesting " + connection_target + ":" + target_port.ToString());

            serverClient = new TcpClient(connection_target, target_port);


            /* *****************************************************
            * reply part
            * ***************************************************** */

            if (serverClient.Connected)
            {
                // reply successful audience
                byte[] reply = new byte[10];
                //version
                reply[0] = SOCKS_VERSION ;
                // replycode
                reply[1] = SOCKS_REPLYSUCCESS ;
                //reserved and 0
                reply[2] = 0;
                // addresstype
                reply[3] = 1;
                string ip = serverClient.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
                IPAddress ipaddr = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
                reply[4] = ipaddr.GetAddressBytes()[0];
                reply[5] = ipaddr.GetAddressBytes()[1];
                reply[6] = ipaddr.GetAddressBytes()[2];
                reply[7] = ipaddr.GetAddressBytes()[3];
                int port = int.Parse(serverClient.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[1]);
                // read unsigned integer in networkoctet order
                reply[8] = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)port)[0];
                reply[9] = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)port)[1];
                socksClientStream.Write(reply, 0, 10);
                Console.WriteLine("writing reply");

               /* *****************************************************
                * tcp redirection
                * ***************************************************** */


                NetworkStream serverClientStream = serverClient.GetStream();

                bool ioError = false;

                // forward tcp data till one of the connected endpoints is disconnected
                while (serverClient.Connected && socksClient.Connected && !ioError )
                {
                     ....
                }
```